# Oracle XML: extract child tag names

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g

How to select all child tags name by xpath?

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
  DATA VARCHAR2(4000) NOT NULL ENABLE
)
```

with some XML data in `DATA` filed like this:

```
<foo>
  <a>some</a>
  <b>another</b>
  <c>some else<c>
</foo>
```

I want to extract all tags from 2nd level:

```
select xmltype(DATA).extract('/foo/*').getRootElement() as MY_TAGS form Foo;
```

(I expected a list like this)

```
a
b
c
```

But I got a result of `null` values:

```
(null)
(null)
(null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from xmltable('foo/*'  passing xmltype('<foo>
  <a>some</a>
  <b>another</b>
  <c>some else</c>
</foo>') 
columns 
tag_name varchar2(100) path 'name()',
tag_value varchar2(100) path 'text()'    
)
```